# Why is there a 1 at the end of my printed array?

Tags: php, arrays, printing

This is a super simple array print, but I'm getting at the end when I use print_r.

```
<?php 
  $user_names = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
  $results = print_r($user_names);
  echo $results;
?>
```

Then I get:

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => 1
     [1] => 2
     [2] => 3
     [3] => 4
 )
 1
```

Comment: print_r has a second parameter, called `return`. Set this to true if you're echoing a print_r

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) already prints the array - there is no need to `echo` its return value (which is `true` and thus will end up as `1` when converted to a string):

> When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is TRUE.

The following would work fine, too:

```
$results = print_r($user_names, true);
echo $results;
```

It makes no sense at all though unless you don't *always* display the results right after getting them.

Comment: Gosh, you guys are all so good on this site. So much to learn... Thanks!

Comment: I've used the print_r($var,$true); to capture something  (Like the $_SESSION)as a quick and dirty debug technique, and have teh server email it to me.

Answer (score 0):

You get it because of

```
echo $results;
```

Since **$results** contains the result of [print_r](https://www.php.net/print_r) function which is TRUE (1)

print_r can return the string instead of echoing it. To do this, you must pass a second argument - true:

```
$results = print_r($user_names, true);
```

So, you have two options. Either remove echo $results or leave it, but pass a second argument to print_r.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` prints the result in the screen, if you need to return a string instead of printing, you should pass a second argument to the function:

```
<?php 
$user_names = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$results = print_r($user_names, true);
echo $results;
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 0):

`print_r`  actually prints out the results,  if you would like it to return the results,  use `print_r($user_name, true)'`

so either of these will do what you want.

```
<?php 
  $user_names = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
  print_r($user_names);
 ?>
```

or

```
 <?php 
   $user_names = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
   $results = print_r($user_names,true);
    echo $results;
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave `print_r` no second argument, it will do the printing itself and return a 1. you then save this one and print it.  Try:

```
$results = print_r($user_names, true);
```

Check out the docs for [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> If you would like to capture the output of `print_r()`, use the return parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it.