# Why is the "1" appended?

Tags: php

In this program

```
<?php  

    $bp = array();  
echo print_r($bp).'<BR>';  

?>
```

why is there a "1" appended when the echo executes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there a 1 at the end of my printed array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145821/why-is-there-a-1-at-the-end-of-my-printed-array)

Answer (score 3):

Because by default `print_r()` returns a status 1 = ok 0 = failed

So you should code the `print_r()` without the `echo` as its output goes direct to the output stream and the echo is unnecessary.

You also need to echo the `<br>` seperately.

```
<?php  

$bp = array();  
print_r($bp);
echo '<BR>';  

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `print_r()` prints the output itself and returns `TRUE`, which is converted to `1` when it gets echoed.

If you want `print_r()` to return its result instead of printing, so you can concatenate it, give it a second argument `TRUE`.

```
echo print_r($bp, true).'<BR>';
```

Answer (score 2):

If printing with `print_r()` is successful `print_r()` returns true you can use `print_r($youVar,true)` to have it removed.